# How to hide plugin submenu title in drop down in admin panel in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, add-submenu-page

I have created a plugin that has some sub menus i.e add new & list, besides that I also have pages to update the data, But I don't want to display these sub menus in dropdown.
Here is my code.

```
add_submenu_page(
"testimonial",
"Manage Testimonial",
"Manage Testimonial",
"manage_options",
"manage-testimonial",
"manage_testimonial"
```

);

```
add_submenu_page(
"testimonial",
null,
null,
"manage_options",
"edit-testimonial",
"edit_testimonial"
```

);

If I use this it adds blank ul for these, How can I do this.
This is the admin panel drop down.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Renaming submenu "parent slug" option to null is the solution to this.

```
add_submenu_page(
null,
null,
null,
"manage_options",
"edit-testimonial",
"edit_testimonial"
);
```